# scope of function declaration in c

Tags: c, function, calling-convention, function-declaration

i have read in various places that functions which are declared in main() cannot be called outside main. But in below program fun3() is declared inside main() and called outside main() in other functions, and IT WORKS, giving output 64.here's link
http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/7EZZxQ .however,if i change fun3() return type int to void ,it fails to compile,whats reason for this behaviour?

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    void fun1(int);
    void fun2(int);
    int fun3(int); 

    int num = 5;
    fun1(num);
    fun2(num);
}

void fun1(int no)
{
    no++;
    fun3(no);
}

void fun2(int no)
{
    no--;
    fun3(no);

}

int fun3(int n)
{
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

there is fail in compilation when declaration of fun3() is changed.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    void fun1(int);
    void fun2(int);
    void fun3(int);     //fun3 return type changed to void error in compilation

    int num = 5;
    fun1(num);
    fun2(num);
}

void fun1(int no)
{
    no++;
    fun3(no);
}

void fun2(int no)
{
    no--;
    fun3(no);

}

void fun3(int n)   //fun3 return type changed to void error in compilation
{
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

Comment: While my answer is an educated guess, it would be helpful if you told us what compiler you are using, what version of it, and what error you get when you change the argument (should probably show us the changed code as well).

Comment: Compile with all warnings on (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc), read up on what the compiler tells you and (may be) get enlightened.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i have included the link of online compiler in the question... i will update the code with the one where its getting wrong :)

Comment: Doesn't compile with C99: https://ideone.com/we74Jf You didn't specify a C Standard, so we can assume it is C99 ( or C11 ).

Comment: @this aha...!! i think this answered the question..thanks:)

Comment: @this GCC, without any specific flag to tell the version, defaults to C89 which allows the function deducing..

Comment: @codeluv Also note that saying that a function returns something (like in the first version) and not actually returning anything is the path to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to the C99 standard, if the compiler saw a function *call* without a function *declaration* in the same scope, it assumed that the function returned `int`.

Neither `fun1` nor `fun2` *declare* `fun3` before they call it, nor do they see the declaration in `main`; the declaration of `fun3` in `main` is limited to the body of `main`.  Under C89 and earlier, the compiler will assume that the call to `fun3` returns an `int`.  In the first example, the *definition* of `fun3` returns an `int` so the code will compile under a C89 compiler.  In the second example, the definition of `fun3` returns `void`, which doesn't match the assumed `int` type, so the code fails to compile.

Under C99 and later standards, *neither* snippet will compile; the compiler no longer assumes an implicit `int` declaration for a function call.  *All* functions must be explicitly declared or defined before they are called.

Answer (score 1):

Declarations are only valid in the scope they are declared in. *However*, in older C standards, the compiler was allowed to *guess* function declarations if none existed at the time of the call, which is probably what happens in your case: The compiler sees the call of `fun3` in `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3`, and deduces (guesses) the argument types based on the argument you pass in the call.

Comment: so according to you probably they are implementing older standards..?and what about void...why it fails with void fun3(int)? @joachim pilebrog

Comment: @codeluv I really can't say, because I don't know exactly what changes you made or what errors you get.

Comment: @codeluv The compiler, when it guesses the function declaration, defaults to guess the function returns `int`, if the actual function definition is different from what the compiler deduces, then you will get an error because the declaration and definition doesn't match.